# Shared and non shared element enter/exit transition for Activity

Tags: android, android-transitions

I am trying to achieve enter/exit transition similar to Google Play. Steps are following:

Enter:

> 1. Transition moves clicked image to top
> 2. At the same time other content slides from bottom

Exit:

> 1. Shared image slides to top
> 2. Other content slides to bottom

The shared image works properly in enter transition, but how to override the exit transition that it doesn't reverse the shared element transition and also define enter/exit transition to the content which is not shared element.

Is there a way to create these transitions using `TransitionSet` that it contains both shared element and non shared element transitions for enter/exit?

Thanks.